# Saving a matrix with columns' header in python

Tags: python, numpy, import

I have the following code. When i save it. The headers of columns don't save. Could u please guide me?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

A = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=36).reshape(6, 6)

df = pd.DataFrame(A,  columns=['one', 'two', 'three','four','five','six'])
np.savetxt("/home/dataset/test.csv",df, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: `savetxt` takes a `header` parameter.  Format your column names as a string and use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in `pandas` function for this:

```
df.to_csv("your_file_path_here")
```